# ImportError on spconv

Tags: python, importerror

all. I've been annoyed with library "spconv".

I have successfully installed spconv and even tested it with:

```
(pointgroup) hsy@716-server3:/home/ubuntu/hdd1/hsy/One-Thing-One-Click/relation/lib/spconv/dist$ python
Python 3.7.11 (default, Jul 27 2021, 14:32:16) 
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import spconv
>>> exit()
```

It works well.

However, when I tried to use it in the second attempt, it showed:

```
(pointgroup) hsy@716-server3:/home/ubuntu/hdd1/hsy/One-Thing-One-Click/3D-U-Net$ python
Python 3.7.11 (default, Jul 27 2021, 14:32:16) 
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import spconv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/hdd1/hsy/One-Thing-One-Click/3D-U-Net/spconv/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from spconv import utils
  File "/home/ubuntu/hdd1/hsy/One-Thing-One-Click/3D-U-Net/spconv/utils/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from spconv import spconv_utils
ImportError: cannot import name 'spconv_utils' from 'spconv' (/home/ubuntu/hdd1/hsy/One-Thing-One-Click/3D-U-Net/spconv/__init__.py)
>>>
```

How can that happen? Have you ever met this problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: There is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/traveller59/second.pytorch/issues/151) about this...

Comment: Thanks for noticing! I'll go and check it.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/traveller59/second.pytorch/issues/151#issuecomment-1002687904

Simply follow his instructions and it's solved. ^w^